# GraphPlot3D: How to plot undirected graph with a list of edges?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I have a list of edges defined based on vertices like this:

```
Edges={{2, 1}, {10, 9}, {11, 10}, {11, 4}, {17, 12},.....} 
(*Where each number is the index of a vertex which has 3D coordinates*)
```

In order to plot a graph I first made Edges looks like this (I want to plot **undirected** graph)

```
edges = Flatten[Table[{Edges[[i, 1]] <-> Edges[[i, 2]]}, {i, 1, Length[Edges]}]];
```

Then I plot the graph

```
GraphPlot3D[edges, VertexLabeling -> False, (*VertexCoordinateRules -> nodescoord*), \BoxRatios -> Automatic,ViewPoint -> {0, 0, -Infinity}];
```

Where am I wrong? Is it the way I define edges using "<->"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Graph[]` instead of `GraphPlot[]`

```
n = 8;
vC = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {n, 3}];
edges = UndirectedEdge @@@ Subsets[Range@n, {2}];
Graph[edges, VertexCoordinates -> vC]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: @ belisarius，Thanks, I thought graph can only display 2D images. But why VertexLabels -> "Name" property fails. And, is there a place to share mine and use Mathematica extension packages written by others?

Comment: @novice You can talk about that in chat http://chat.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

> ***Is it the way I define edges using "<->"?***

Yes. If we use `-> (Rule)` instead of `<->` ,`GraphPlot3D` works as expected.

```
SeedRandom[123]
n = 20;
edges = RandomChoice[Subsets[Range@n, {2}], 20];
edgelist = Rule @@@ edges;
coords = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {n, 3}];
GraphPlot3D[edgelist, 
 VertexCoordinateRules -> Thread[Range[n] -> coords], Boxed -> False, 
 ImageSize -> 600, EdgeRenderingFunction -> (Tube[#1, .02] &), 
 ViewPoint -> {0, 0, -Infinity}, 
 VertexRenderingFunction ->
  ({ColorData["Atoms"][RandomInteger[{1, 117}]], Sphere[#1, .04]} &), 
 PlotStyle -> Directive[Specularity[White, 20]]]
```

[image]